# receiving packets from a socket in scapy

Tags: python, sockets, scapy, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I am trying to code a basic packet sniffer by listening to a socket in python and found that we could use the socket library in python and do the following,

```
s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW , socket.ntohs(0x0005))
```

Wanted to know whether if we would do the same in scapy?

Comment: Have you seen [Sniffing](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sniffing)?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Scapy Documentnat](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sniffing):

```
from scapy.all import sniff

data = sniff(filter="icmp and host 127.0.0.1", count=2)

print data.summary()
```